Python Flask dynamic logging level change does not work properly
I've been struggling with this issue for a while, and just can't get a grip on what's wrong. I am making my custom logger class by going through a bunch of tutorial articles on this subject. Everything is working pretty well so far, but I have this unexpected issue with the dynamic change of the logger level: it does not go below the initial logging level, with which the app was started. If I start it at INFO, the changes work perfectly fine when I go up, to WARNING or ERROR, but if I set it to DEBUG, it still cuts off the logs at the INFO. The most confusing part is that from the logs I also see that the logger level seems to be changing just fine.
Here's the part of the app.py:
from flask import Flask, redirect, request, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

from custom_logger import CustomLogger
appLogger = CustomLogger("appLogger")

@app.route("/")
def main():
    return render_template("main.html")

@app.route("/logger/level/<logger_level>")
def logger_set_level(logger_level):
    appLogger.critical("Logger old level: {}".format(appLogger.level))
    appLogger.setLevel(logger_level)
    appLogger.critical("Logger new level: {}".format(appLogger.level))
    appLogger.critical("Critical message...")
    appLogger.error("Error message...")
    appLogger.warning("Warning message...")
    appLogger.info("Info message...")
    appLogger.debug("Debug message...")
    return redirect("/")

@app.route("/logger/test")
def logger_test():
    appLogger.critical("Current log level: {}".format(appLogger.level))
    appLogger.critical("Critical error message...")
    appLogger.error("Error message...")
    appLogger.warning("Warning message...")
    appLogger.info("Info message...")
    appLogger.debug("Debug message...")
    return redirect("/")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()


Here's the logger file:
import logging
import configparser


config = configparser.ConfigParser()


class CustomLogger(logging.getLoggerClass()):

    # Levels in integer
    CRITICAL = 50
    ERROR = 40
    WARNING = 30
    INFO = 20
    DEBUG = 10
    NOTSET = 0

    nameToLevel = {
        "critical": CRITICAL,
        "error": ERROR,
        "warning": WARNING,
        "info": INFO,
        "debug": DEBUG,
        "notset": NOTSET
    }

    loggingLevels = {
        "critical": logging.CRITICAL,
        "error": logging.ERROR,
        "warning": logging.WARNING,
        "info": logging.INFO,
        "debug": logging.DEBUG
    }

    def __init__(self, loggerName, loggerLevel="error",
                 consoleFormat="%(levelname)s in %(filename)s - def %(funcName)s(): %(message)s",
                 fileFormat="%(asctime)s - %(filename) -16s %(funcName) -16s %(levelname) -8s: %(message)s",
                 formatDateTime="%Y-%m-%d, %H:%M:%S",
                 fileHandlerName="files/logs/app_logs.log",
                 fileHandlerMode="a"):
        super().__init__(loggerName)
        # Configuring the logging level
        config.read("files/config/config.ini")
        config_logger = config["logger"]
        if config_logger["level"] in self.loggingLevels:
            self.setLevel(config_logger["level"])
        else:
            self.setLevel(loggerLevel)
        # Configuring console logging
        self.consoleFormatter = logging.Formatter(consoleFormat)
        self.consoleHandler = logging.StreamHandler()
        self.consoleHandler.setFormatter(self.consoleFormatter)
        self.addHandler(self.consoleHandler)
        # Configuring file logging
        self.fileFormatter = logging.Formatter(fileFormat, datefmt=formatDateTime)
        self.fileHandler = logging.FileHandler(fileHandlerName, mode=fileHandlerMode)
        self.fileHandler.setFormatter(self.fileFormatter)
        self.addHandler(self.fileHandler)

    def setLevel(self, level):
        if isinstance(level, str):
            if level not in self.loggingLevels:
                raise ValueError("Unknown level: %r" % level)
            config["logger"]["level"] = level
            with open("files/config/config.ini", "w") as config_file:
                config.write(config_file)
            self.level = self.nameToLevel.get(level) # I've tried this and the option below
            # super().setLevel(self.loggingLevels.get(level))
            for handler in self.handlers:
                print("Old: {}".format(handler))
                handler.setLevel(self.loggingLevels.get(level))
                print("New: {}".format(handler))
        else:
            raise TypeError("Level is not a valid string: %r" % level)

I've tried what I could find in the tutorial articles and even tried to copy how it's done in the original setLevel method, it just does not work no matter what I do.
Here is the log:
# super().setLevel(self.loggingLevels.get(level))
2024-05-24, 10:26:19 - app.py           logger_test      CRITICAL: Current log level: 20
2024-05-24, 10:26:19 - app.py           logger_test      CRITICAL: Critical error message...
2024-05-24, 10:26:19 - app.py           logger_test      ERROR   : Error message...
2024-05-24, 10:26:19 - app.py           logger_test      WARNING : Warning message...
2024-05-24, 10:26:19 - app.py           logger_test      INFO    : Info message...
2024-05-24, 10:27:03 - app.py           logger_set_level CRITICAL: Logger old level: 20
2024-05-24, 10:27:03 - app.py           logger_set_level CRITICAL: Logger new level: 30
2024-05-24, 10:27:03 - app.py           logger_set_level CRITICAL: Critical message...
2024-05-24, 10:27:03 - app.py           logger_set_level ERROR   : Error message...
2024-05-24, 10:27:03 - app.py           logger_set_level WARNING : Warning message...
2024-05-24, 10:27:21 - app.py           logger_set_level CRITICAL: Logger old level: 30
2024-05-24, 10:27:21 - app.py           logger_set_level CRITICAL: Logger new level: 10
2024-05-24, 10:27:21 - app.py           logger_set_level CRITICAL: Critical message...
2024-05-24, 10:27:21 - app.py           logger_set_level ERROR   : Error message...
2024-05-24, 10:27:21 - app.py           logger_set_level WARNING : Warning message...
2024-05-24, 10:27:21 - app.py           logger_set_level INFO    : Info message...
# self.level = self.nameToLevel.get(level)
2024-05-24, 10:31:11 - app.py           logger_test      CRITICAL: Current log level: 20
2024-05-24, 10:31:11 - app.py           logger_test      CRITICAL: Critical error message...
2024-05-24, 10:31:11 - app.py           logger_test      ERROR   : Error message...
2024-05-24, 10:31:11 - app.py           logger_test      WARNING : Warning message...
2024-05-24, 10:31:11 - app.py           logger_test      INFO    : Info message...
2024-05-24, 10:31:20 - app.py           logger_set_level CRITICAL: Logger old level: 20
2024-05-24, 10:31:20 - app.py           logger_set_level CRITICAL: Logger new level: 30
2024-05-24, 10:31:20 - app.py           logger_set_level CRITICAL: Critical message...
2024-05-24, 10:31:20 - app.py           logger_set_level ERROR   : Error message...
2024-05-24, 10:31:20 - app.py           logger_set_level WARNING : Warning message...
2024-05-24, 10:31:26 - app.py           logger_set_level CRITICAL: Logger old level: 30
2024-05-24, 10:31:26 - app.py           logger_set_level CRITICAL: Logger new level: 10
2024-05-24, 10:31:26 - app.py           logger_set_level CRITICAL: Critical message...
2024-05-24, 10:31:26 - app.py           logger_set_level ERROR   : Error message...
2024-05-24, 10:31:26 - app.py           logger_set_level WARNING : Warning message...
2024-05-24, 10:31:26 - app.py           logger_set_level INFO    : Info message...


So, the logger level from old to new seems to be changing, but the logs still won't go below INFO, from which they've started, when the app was launched.
